# Matlab: Adding third dimenstion to 2D plot

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot, 2d

I have the following code to generate me a 2D plot or 2 normal distributions:

```
        res = zeros(2, 320); 
        index = 1:320;

        % assign some data to the res array and then approximate:  

        PD = fitdist(index','normal', 'frequency', res(1,:)')
        pdfNormal = normpdf(index',PD.mu,PD.sigma);
        plot(index', pdfNormal, 'Color', 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);
        hold on;
        PD = fitdist(index','normal', 'frequency', res(2,:)')
        pdfNormal = normpdf(index',PD.mu,PD.sigma);
        plot(index', pdfNormal, 'Color', 'b', 'LineWidth', 2);
```

This code generates me then the following picture:

[image: 2D Plot of my data]

Now I am wondering how I could add a third dimension to this plot? Essentially,
I would like to plot another 2 normal distributions, but this time in the Z-axis,
ie., in the third dimension.

Anyone an idea how I could do that easily?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Use [plot3](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/plot3.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can simply give the plots different z-values. Example:

```
%# some random data
x = 1:300;
y = zeros(5,300);
for i=1:5
    y(i,:) = normpdf(x,100+i*20,10);
end

%# plot
hold on
clr = lines(5);
h = zeros(5,1);
for i=1:5
    h(i) = plot(x, y(i,:), 'Color',clr(i,:), 'LineWidth',2);
    set(h(i), 'ZData',ones(size(x))*i)
end
zlim([0 6]), box on, grid on
view(3)
hold off
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Talk about awesome solution! xD xD xD
I retrofitted to my own needs & data and I must say it worked like a charm! :] Many thanks ;)